# Sql oracle using having in update

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
updated EXD set reflog = 'blah' where reflog = 'A0003' having count(*) = '0' ;
```

I'd like to update EXD only if it contains no records at all. How can I do that ?

Thank you

Comment: If there are no records in the table, wouldn't that be an insert instead?

Comment: How can you update something that does not exist?  Maybe you mean it does not exist in a joined table?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, only if select * from EXD where reflog = 'blah' return 0 record

Comment: @user1058398 - It returned no records, what would you then update?

Comment: Or u mean null values

Answer (score 1):

This would work, but not sure if it makes sense as you will
be updating all records in EXD Table if a record does
not exist with reflog A0003

```
update EXD
set reflog = 'blah'
where NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT     1
     FROM       EXD x
     where      x.reflog = 'A0003')
```